# how to change Environment map texture dynamically on reflection material

Tags: three.js

in threejs i want to change the skybox textures dynamically, am added 2 scenes here so i attached one scene to my skybox, so i decided to remove the skybox before switch from on texture to another, and the skybox textures are reflecting Environmentmap on the object, if i change the textures by select from the given list, am checking textures with the switch case and adding the texture , the reflection on the object is working, but if i switch skyBoxMaterial to selected texture Enviromentmap changed successfully but the reflection on the object is not changed to current Enviromentmap

Following is my code:

```
function envmap(envmap)
            {

                switch(envmap)
                {
                case 'canary':

                     var urls = [
                          'textures/cube/canary/pos-x.png',
                          'textures/cube/canary/neg-x.png',
                          'textures/cube/canary/pos-y.png',
                          'textures/cube/canary/neg-y.png',
                          'textures/cube/canary/pos-z.png',
                          'textures/cube/canary/neg-z.png'
                        ];
                    //var cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls); // load textures
                break;

                case 'Park2':

                     var urls = [
                          'textures/cube/Park2/posx.jpg',
                          'textures/cube/Park2/negx.jpg',
                          'textures/cube/Park2/posy.jpg',
                          'textures/cube/Park2/negy.jpg',
                          'textures/cube/Park2/posz.jpg',
                          'textures/cube/Park2/negz.jpg'
                        ];
                    //var cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls); // load textures
                break;

                case 'Park3Med':

                     var urls = [
                          'textures/cube/Park3Med/px.jpg',
                          'textures/cube/Park3Med/nx.jpg',
                          'textures/cube/Park3Med/py.jpg',
                          'textures/cube/Park3Med/ny.jpg',
                          'textures/cube/Park3Med/pz.jpg',
                          'textures/cube/Park3Med/nz.jpg'
                        ];
                    //var cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls); // load textures
                break;

                case 'Bridge2':

                     var urls = [
                          'textures/cube/Bridge2/posx.jpg',
                          'textures/cube/Bridge2/negx.jpg',
                          'textures/cube/Bridge2/posy.jpg',
                          'textures/cube/Bridge2/negy.jpg',
                          'textures/cube/Bridge2/posz.jpg',
                          'textures/cube/Bridge2/negz.jpg'
                        ];
                    //var cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls); // load textures
                break;

                case 'pisa':

                     var urls = [
                          'textures/cube/pisa/px.png',
                          'textures/cube/pisa/nx.png',
                          'textures/cube/pisa/py.png',
                          'textures/cube/pisa/ny.png',
                          'textures/cube/pisa/pz.png',
                          'textures/cube/pisa/nz.png'
                        ];
                    //var cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls); // load textures
                break;

                default:

                 var urls = [
                          'textures/cube/canary/pos-x.png',
                          'textures/cube/canary/neg-x.png',
                          'textures/cube/canary/pos-y.png',
                          'textures/cube/canary/neg-y.png',
                          'textures/cube/canary/pos-z.png',
                          'textures/cube/canary/neg-z.png'
                        ];

                break;
                }

                    var cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls,undefined, render); // load textures
                    cubemap.needsUpdate = true;

                    cubemap.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

                    var shader = THREE.ShaderLib['cube']; // init cube shader from built-in lib
                    shader.uniforms['tCube'].value = cubemap; // apply textures to shader

                    // create shader material
                    var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
                      fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
                      vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
                      uniforms: shader.uniforms,
                      depthWrite: false,
                      side: THREE.BackSide
                    });

                alert(skybox);
                if (skybox)
                {
                sceneCube.remove(skybox);   
                }

                skybox = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1000, 1000, 1000 ), skyBoxMaterial );
                sceneCube.add( skybox );

                    var reflectionMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color: 0xcccccc,
                      envMap: cubemap
                    });


                    var object = scene.getObjectByName ("myname", true);

                    object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )
                    {
                    //child.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
                    var  geometry = child.geometry;
                    //console.log(geometry);

                    material = child.material;
                    material.transparent = true;

                    child.material.needsUpdate = true;

                    child.material.map = reflectionMaterial;

                    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, reflectionMaterial);
                    scene.add(mesh);


                    }
                    });



            }
```

Comment: 1. With all due respect, you need to practice debugging your code yourself. Use `three.js`, not `three.min.js`for that purpose. Ask questions about three.js, not help-me-debug-my-code-questions. 2. Remove the `needsUpdate` flags, and add them only when needed. 3. What is `child.material.map = reflectionMaterial` ???

Comment: Hi @WestLangley thank you so much for the valuable reply, i tried myself to debug the code, but failed so only am asking the question to debug,, `child.material.map = reflectionMaterial` is the traverse of the object with the where `reflectionMaterial` is`var reflectionMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color: 0xcccccc,
                      envMap: cubemap
                    });`

Comment: and now am getting `TypeError: offset is undefined` in three.js online `25341` i will try to fix it

Comment: `child.material.map` is a `THREE.Texture`. `reflectionMaterial` is a `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial`.

Comment: so we can't apply `reflectionMaterial` to `child.material.map` ?? actually i want a Environment for an object, and that the Environment reflection will apply to my model as like in the attached image http://imgur.com/5ZGmwpv, it is working fine, but while switch from one Environment to others i can't override the reflection on object it still on the old environment reflection

Comment: Hi @WestLangley i need the reflection exactly like http://imgur.com/p4FeZ56, so tried this way and it worked, am only having issue with the environment reflection on switch over one from another, now u will be clear i think..

Comment: @WestLangley see here the working example with `three.js`http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs424/notes2013/threejs/reflection-demo.html i want the same action here with my obj model

Comment: @WestLangley Maybe we should consider starting using getters/setters to check type so we can avoid people setting materials to texture properties... hmmm... Javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the work around fixed it myself

i used `child.material=reflectionMaterial;` instead of  `child.material.map = reflectionMaterial;` and the refection is worked on the object material

So now while switch from one environment to another environment the reflection applied to my Object too

and there is no need of add new mesh below

```
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, reflectionMaterial);
  scene.add(mesh);
```